# Book about a girl finding out her father is from another planet

Tags: story-identification, books

Book about a girl finding out her father is from another planet. A medium tells her on her 11th or 13th birthday to light a black candle. She keeps having these visions of a different place that her alien father is at.

I remember at the end her friend shouting at her as she's taken up in a beam of light from a UFO?? I think the cover had part of her face on it and had a green like aura to it?